# Nested Components Taking CSS Based On Type in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I noticed that there's a discrepancy in React where a CSS file won't be applied to nested components unless they're a class that extends React.Component:

```
A.css:
Button {
  background-color: blue;
}

Main.tsx:
import '../A.css';
return <>
  <FirstAttempt /> <- This works, A.css applies to Test 1
  <SecondAttempt /> <- This does not work, Test 2 does not get A.css
</>

FirstAttempt.tsx:
class FirstAttempt() extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
    return <Button>Test 1</Button>
  }
}

FirstAttempt.tsx:
function SecondAttempt() 
{
  return <Button>Test 2</Button>;
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Edit: I found the source of my original issue but I believe this is a problem with some CSS attributes and not others. Ex: border-radius has this issue but background-color does not.

Comment: Seems like a problem with css itself. I don't quite understand, what you are trying to style in `A.css`. You write selector `Button` which looks like you are trying to reference all of the `<Button />` components? But it doesn't work this way, writing `Button` in CSS is same as writing `button`, so it will style all html `<button>` tags. Maybe this is an issue, maybe `<FirstAttempt>` and `<SecondAttempt>` use different implementations of `<Button>`, one of which is a simple html button and the other not? Please provide code of `<Button />` and the rest of component's code if there is